# Replace an arrary<String> with an new value

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have a `String type list List<String> DataEnqueryDateDsc` which have a value like - "John Rodriguez,214,07-05-2013 11:14:14,Hot","Saleem Ertrtt,208,08-05-2013 14:48:43,Hot",.....

**List DataEnqueryDateDsc = "John Rodriguez,214,07-05-2013 11:14:14,Hot","Saleem Ertrtt,208,08-05-2013 14:48:43,Hot"**
I want to replace this arary list with only **08-05-2013 14:48:43** value.

Comment: DataEnqueryDateDsc.clear(); and DataEnqueryDateDsc.add("08-05-2013 14:48:43 ");

Answer (score 1):

you can make a  new array, then loop the list,then split the every var and extract what you want put into the  new array